# Laravel SQL retornando com interrogação?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

Estou fazendo uma consulta no `Laravel` e ele esta retornando a data com o seguinte valor.

```
select `campo` from `tabela` where `campodotipodata` = ?
```

bom ele retorna assim o `SQL`, segue o código no `LARAVEL`

```
$vardata = date('Y-m-d');
$cardapios = $this->tabela->where('campodotipodata', '=', $vardata)
                ->select('campo')->toSql();//get();
```

Comment: é assim mesmo no lugar daquele `?` ele vai colocar a data na hora que você chamar o `get()`, por exemplo, mas, diz ai qual é a duvida?

Comment: ele não retorna nada apesar de ter dados no banco.. O toSql é porque estava testando

Comment: Além disso, como esta gravado essa data?

Answer (score 2):

Sim realmente, o [eloquent](/questions/tagged/eloquent) usa [PreparedStatements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php), isso significa que o valor é substituído pelo posicionamento (espaços reservados) e seguindo uma ordem que é estabelecido no desenvolvimento.

Se por ventura quiser saber os dados enviados e a `SQL` gerada faça o seguinte:

```
$vardata = date('Y-m-d');
$builder = $this->tabela->where('campodotipodata', '=', $vardata)->select('campo');
```

`SQL` gerada:

```
var_dump($builder->toSql());
```

Valores e sua ordens, que é ou serão substituido(s) no(s) espaço(s) reservado(s):

```
var_dump($builder->getBindings());
```

<sub>***Referencias***</sub>

- [PreparedStatements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)
- [Eloquent query ->toSql returning '?' for 3rd argument??](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/eloquent-query-tosql-returning-for-3rd-argument)
- [Debugging Queries in Laravel](https://scotch.io/tutorials/debugging-queries-in-laravel)
- [Builder.html#method_toSql](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_toSql)
- [Builder.html#method_getBindings](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.html#method_getBindings)